# Is it possible to recover this USB Drive?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I have a problem with my USB Stick. It simply doesn't show up in **fdisk -l**.
I suppose it's dead (totally not possible to recover programmatically), but I'm just curious if it's wrong.

Here are some logs taken when I plug it in (ask if you need anything else):

```
helveticau :: /home/helveticau » sudo dmesg        
[ 4626.991027] audit: type=1106 audit(1575469961.482:265): pid=156058 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[ 4626.991171] audit: type=1104 audit(1575469961.482:266): pid=156058 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[ 4636.065432] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[ 4636.209306] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1665, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 4636.209312] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4636.209316] usb 1-1: Product: DataTraveler 2.0
[ 4636.209319] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[ 4636.209321] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 6C626D7C2801FD40B96323C7
[ 4636.210738] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4636.215005] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 4637.332845] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     GENERIC  USB Mass Storage 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4 CCS
[ 4637.335313] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4637.335321] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
[ 4637.335364] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
[ 4637.335384] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 4637.335391] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
[ 4637.335650] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 4637.335656] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00
[ 4637.335894] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 4637.338182] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4637.338189] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
[ 4637.338196] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
[ 4637.338656] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 4643.783335] audit: type=1101 audit(1575469978.276:267): pid=156703 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_time acct="helveticau" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[ 4643.783784] audit: type=1110 audit(1575469978.276:268): pid=156703 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_env acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
[ 4643.791688] audit: type=1105 audit(1575469978.282:269): pid=156703 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
helveticau :: /home/helveticau »
helveticau :: /home/helveticau »
helveticau :: /home/helveticau » lsusb                 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a07 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0951:1665 Kingston Technology Digital DataTraveler SE9 64GB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
helveticau :: /home/helveticau »
helveticau :: /home/helveticau »
helveticau :: /home/helveticau » ls -la /dev/disk/by-id
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 220 Dec  4 16:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 Dec  4 11:12 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Dec  4 16:14 ata-TOSHIBA_THNSNK128GVN8_48NS10XKTMYT -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  4 16:14 ata-TOSHIBA_THNSNK128GVN8_48NS10XKTMYT-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  4 16:14 ata-TOSHIBA_THNSNK128GVN8_48NS10XKTMYT-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  4 16:14 ata-TOSHIBA_THNSNK128GVN8_48NS10XKTMYT-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Dec  4 16:32 usb-GENERIC_USB_Mass_Storage_6C626D7C2801FD40B96323C7-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Dec  4 16:14 wwn-0x500080d911070188 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  4 16:14 wwn-0x500080d911070188-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  4 16:14 wwn-0x500080d911070188-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Dec  4 16:14 wwn-0x500080d911070188-part3 -> ../../sda3
helveticau :: /home/helveticau »
helveticau :: /home/helveticau »
helveticau :: /home/helveticau » sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 119.25 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA THNSNK12
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4E7A8A53-F0A1-D148-94BE-44437DF859B8

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   5244927   4194304     2G Linux swap
/dev/sda3  5244928 250069646 244824719 116.8G Linux root (x86-64)
helveticau :: /home/helveticau » sudo fdisk /dev/sdb                                                                 

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No such file or directory
helveticau :: /home/helveticau »
helveticau :: /home/helveticau »
helveticau :: /home/helveticau » lsblk                     
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
+-sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /mnt/A1DB-B2C8__
+-sda2   8:2    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
+-sda3   8:3    0 116.8G  0 part /
helveticau :: /home/helveticau »
helveticau :: /home/helveticau »
helveticau :: /home/helveticau » lsbusb -v
[. . .]
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0951:1665 Kingston Technology Digital DataTraveler SE9 64GB
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0951 Kingston Technology
  idProduct          0x1665 Digital DataTraveler SE9 64GB
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0020
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval             255
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval             255

[. . .]
```

Comment: Try it in another computer just in case. If still undetected then it's probably beyond repair.

Comment: I did. I tried on my PC (Windows) and laptop (Arch Linux, logs above). Windows says something like "You should format the disk in the drive before you can use it." . And then Windows is unable to format the disk

Comment: They're really not worth fighting once they start to go. Just bin it & save all the hassle. I used to get through literally thousands of these things for work.

Comment: Yes, it's easy to buy a new usb stick. But I'm just curious if it can be fixed. Probably not.

Comment: Did you use dd or similar software to create a bootable flash drive. That creates a hybrid DVD/flash drive configuration that has no partitions. And data in partition area(MBR) often confuses partitioning tools. If so use dd to clear start of drive and then see if partitioning works. Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive

Comment: @oldfred No, I didn't. Also dd says 'no space left on device'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try formatting it with [rufus](https://rufus.ie/). It has saved me 4-5 times.

*Windows* failed to format & reuse them. Sometimes, the pen drives were not even detected by **Disk Management**, **My Computer** folder & other *Windows* utilities.
Rufus detected the drive, formatted it & made it reusable instantly!

[ I assume it is all good with OS, BIOS & PC hardware ( USB ports, etc.) and the pen drive is not corrupted / damaged physically. ]